# React Native Navigation - Bottom tabs overflow

Tags: wix-react-native-navigation

How do we add a More tab menu (like iOS overflow menu) in bottom tab bar in V2 React-native-navigation (wix)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RNN V2 automatically adds a overflow button when it has > 5 tabs.
Closing this Question.